# vim - Stop scrolling after first file ending

Tags: vim

By default when you scroll down to the end of a displayed buffer in a vim window, you can scroll until the last file line is on first line of the vim display area. All other lines of the display area are marked with "~" characters.
Is there a configuration to stop scrolling when the last file line is at the bottom of the vim window?

Edit:
To be more precise this behavior only apply to mouse wheel scroll or PgDown key navigation that fill the screen with those non-existant line marks. I the cursor is moved line by line using the down arrow key, it stops correctly at the last file line.

Comment: I wonder if you could manage to get VIM working like you wanted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to align the current line to the bottom of the window.

E.g.  <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

Not surpisingly there is a family of related panning motions:

- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> down
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> up
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> top
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> bottom
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> center (middle)
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> center (middle)

For completeness:

- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> / <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> vertical pan to the right
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> / <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> vertical pan to the left

Also, have a look at `scrolloff`

I use

```
:set scrolloff=2
```

to always keep a minimum buffer of 2 lines before or after the current cursor line. This makes these panning motions almost magical. I spend all day browsing code bases using nothing but

- paging  <kbd>C-d</kbd>/<kbd>C-u</kbd>, hjkl, and frequent panning relocations with (mostly) <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>
- navigating <kbd>}</kbd>/<kbd>{</kbd>
- ctags for all other navigation needs

Comment: Yes I already have a scrolloff setting. But it has no effet with PgDown or mouse wheel scrolling.

Comment: Is there a way to remap PgDown or mouse wheel down scroll to use a combo based on the 'z' command to automatically stop them at the last file line?

Comment: In fact a possible solution is to remap the mouse wheel scroll and page down key to the '}' command. Thanks you for letting me know this navigation commands

Comment: Obviously the solution in my last comment will not work in insert mode... Is there any other combo for scrolling down in insert mode?

Comment: Yup you may use ctrl-O to invoke a normal mode command in insert mode. That said, I don't see the need to scroll in insert mode - it messes up (my brain's tracking of) undo items

Answer (score 2):

I just found this (http://vimrc-dissection.blogspot.se/2009/02/fixing-pageup-and-pagedown.html):

```
map <silent> <PageUp> 1000<C-U>
map <silent> <PageDown> 1000<C-D>
imap <silent> <PageUp> <C-O>1000<C-U>
imap <silent> <PageDown> <C-O>1000<C-D>
```

Which seems to work for the page keys. And after some unsuccessful searching regarding scrolling, I came up with this:

```
map <ScrollWheelUp> H5k
map <ScrollWheelDown> L5j
```

You lose the line, but it's not very useful when scrolling anyway? Alternatively, you can also do:

```
map <ScrollWheelUp> <C-U>
map <ScrollWheelDown> <C-D>
```

If you don't mind very fast scrolling...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. But even if there were, how would you want it to behave if there were less lines in your file than on your screen?  You'd have to display those non-existent lines somehow.

You'd have to have some way to tell vim to display those lines if the top of the file is in view, but not allow them to display if the top isn't in view.

Comment: Of course if the file does not contains enough lines to fill the screen, there is no problem having those non-existant line marks. I just don't want PgDown or mouse wheel scroll going below the end of file

Answer (score 1):

No, your description is not correct.

When you scroll *line by line* down with arrows or with j/k keys, Vim will stop at the bottom of the screen.
That is, it won't *fill the screen* with non-existant lines.

When however, one goes down page by page with PgDown / PgUp, then it can get non-existant lines on the screen. It cannot be avoided, since PgDown / PgUp keys don't jump down line by line.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to avoid: having non existant lines on the screen using either PgDown or mouse wheel scroll!

Comment: @greydet - Well, how would would you like Vim to behave when you PgDown while on the last page?